# How to Change Output name in bash

Tags: bash, macos, macos-catalina

I have Ran the command

```
ioreg -l | grep IOPlatformSerialNumber
```

in MacOS.

It gives output as `IOPlatformSerialNumber`.

I want to Rename the output name from `IOPlatformSerialNumber` to Just `SerialNumber`, How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sed` for that:

```
ioreg -l | grep IOPlatformSerialNumber | sed "s|IOPlatformSerialNumber|SerialNumber|"
```

Answer (score 0):

use `sed`:

```
ioreg -l | sed -n 's/IOPlatformSerialNumber/SerialNumber/p'
```

You don't need `grep` since `sed -n` will filter the output to just the ones where the `s///p` command found a match that needed to be substituted.

Answer (score 0):

You could use sed for it

```
ioreg -l | grep IOPlatformSerialNumber | sed 's/IOPlatformSerialNumber/SerialNumber/'
```